# Magento 2: How to change the position of category

Tags: magento2, theme, custom

I am working simple Magento site and my task is to change position in a category.

[image]

In this screenshot, top category and next to custom header, how to change position first see the custom header and next to see category

code is here:

```
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header"
               as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/header1.phtml"/>
        <move element="custom_header" destination="panel_wrapper" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" as="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/header1.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>

<move element="custom_header" destination="panel_wrapper" before="-"/>
```